# WebStorm JavaScript "Document is not defined"

Tags: javascript

I'm using WebStorm and I'm trying to assign an HTML element to a JavaScript variable.When I run the JS file the following error appears :

```
ion (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var eagle = document.g
                                                                    ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

My JS code is in External file, i guess the problem is somewhere in the WebStorm settings, but i can't find it.here is my code: JavaScript

```
     var eagle = document.getElementById('eagle');
     console.log(eagle);
```

And HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Traverse</title>

</head>
<body>
      <ul>
           <li id="eagle" class="bird">Eagle</li>
      </ul>

<script src="traverse-dom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't run JavaScript code directly from WebStrorm. It may thinks that it deals with node.js code and of cause there is no `document` defined in engine. Run javascript [via browser](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-javascript.html) from your HTML file.

Comment: So if I want to output something like all of the child elements of the selected element I have to see my output in the browser console ?